# kendo splitter: hover event

Tags: hover, kendo-ui, splitter

I would like to run code in the `hover` event in the kendo-ui splitter.
The list of events for the splitter does not contain `hover`, `mouseenter`, `leave` or any of that sort.

Does someone has an idea how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of what you want to achieve...

If you just want to observe the moves of the splitbars, just bind manually the corresponding event to this bar :

```
$(".k-splitbar").on("mousemove", yourHandler);
```